# Image boxes moving smoothly?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I was wondering if there is a way to make image boxes smoothly flow through the form
I have turned on double buffer on the form and it doesn't improve it that much.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Offset As Point
    Dim moveRight As Boolean = True
    Dim moveDown As Boolean = True
    Const Speed As Decimal = 1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If moveRight = True Then
            pxbox.Left += Speed
            If (pxbox.Left + pxbox.Width) > Me.ClientSize.Width Then moveRight = False
        Else
            pxbox.Left -= Speed
            If pxbox.Left < 0 Then moveRight = True

        End If

        If moveDown = True Then
            pxbox.Top += Speed
            If (pxbox.Top + pxbox.Height) > Me.ClientSize.Height Then moveDown = False
        Else
            pxbox.Top -= Speed
            If pxbox.Top <= 0 Then moveDown = True

        End If

        'Collision Method 1
        Dim Col As Boolean = Collision(pxbox, pbpaddle1)
        If Col = True Then
            moveRight = Not moveRight
            moveDown = Not moveDown
        End If

        Dim Col2 As Boolean = Collision(pxbox, pbpaddle2)

        If Col2 = True Then
            moveRight = Not moveRight
            moveDown = Not moveDown
        End If

        'Method 2
        'If pxbox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbpaddle1.Bounds) Then
        '    moveRight = Not moveRight
        '    moveDown = Not moveDown
        'End If
        'If pxbox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbpaddle2.Bounds) Then
        '    moveRight = Not moveRight
        '    moveDown = Not moveDown
        'End If
    End Sub

    Private Function Collision(ByVal P1 As PictureBox, ByVal P2 As PictureBox) As Boolean
        If P1.Left + P1.Width < P2.Left Then Return False
        If P2.Left - 15 + P2.Width < P1.Left Then Return False
        If P1.Top + P1.Height < P2.Top Then Return False
        If P2.Top + P2.Height < P1.Top Then Return False

        Return True

    End Function
```

Comment: What is the interval of your timer?

Comment: set to the highest, 10, thats why my speed is 1 so it can be as smooth as possible but, its still not.

Comment: The WinForm's timer control isn't really designed for this type of animation.  It's accuracy is limited to about 55 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The Winform's Timer control really isn't designed for the kind of accuracy you will need for smooth animation.  You are also going to have  a LOT of overhead trying to use controls for the "sprites" in your animation.

You really should look in to doing all of your drawing using GDI drawing code to a memory bitmap and then posting that bitmap to either a single large image control, the background of your form, or some other display surface.